# Same model has_many and belongs_to to other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Model User should have association:

```
has_many :owner_tasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: 'user_id'
has_many :doer_tasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: 'doer_id'
```

And model Task should have association:

```
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
has_many :doers, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'doer_id'
```

The task should have many doers and only one owner. How right to build this Association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class User
  has_many :owned_tasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :todo_tasks, class_name: 'Task'
end

class Task
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doers, class_name: 'User'
end
```

With this migration (for Rails 5):

```
class RelateUsersToTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.references :owner, index: true
    end
    create_join_table :tasks, :users do |t|
      t.index :task_id
      t.index :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

After migration I believe you would be able to

```
user.owned_tasks # => [task1, task2, ...]
user.todo_tasks # => [task1, task2, ...]
task.owner # => user1
task.doers # => [user1, user2, ...]
```

Comment: i have error when i try create task object `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "tasks_users" does not exist`

Comment: @AlexandrDmitrenko Sorry I didn't try. The new version should work.